# Disable magento image cache

Tags: magento2, product-images, cache

Is it possible to disable Magento 2 image cache (it's consuming 41G), I want to use S3 for images since I expect our images to go over 2TB in few months, I am afraid generating cache on S3 may take too much time and result in inconsistencies. So is there a way to disable magento image cache?

I do not see image cache under Cache Management.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just like in Magento1 there's no setting in Magento2 for disabling the image cache.

If you really don't want Magento to cache your images, you'll need to go through all your template files where you're calling the image and replace the code to load the image from the attribute model instead of the media init.

Comment: can you please update the sample code for loading product image from attribute model in product detail page. @Hamim

Answer (score -1):

Hello you can enable/disable cache by going in
Magento backend, go to 
System > Tools > Cache Management
Check image cache box select disable from action then save it this will disable image cache. Hope this might help.

Comment: Thanks for reply Abhi, but I do not see Image Cache check box under Cache Management, see the screenshot I have attached.